# How do I set the checked state of all items in a winforms Checkedlistbox programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows form Application.
I want to `check/uncheck` all checkboxes in checkedlistbox.

I am using following code to generate checkboxes dynamically.

```
    var CheckCollection = new List<CheckedBoxFiller>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        CheckCollection.Add(new CheckedBoxFiller {
                                Text = dr["ImageName"].ToString(),
                                Value = dr["ImageId"].ToString()
        });
    chklbEvidenceTags.DataSource = CheckCollection;
    chklbEvidenceTags.DisplayMember = "Text";
    chklbEvidenceTags.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And this is the CheckboxFiller class

```
private class CheckedBoxFiller {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to `check/Uncheck` `all checkboxes`. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be useful.

Comment: What is checkedboxlist in winforms? And your class have onle 2 string properties - where is bool?

Comment: @JleruOHeP ,Thanks for drawing attention to mistake. Sorry I typed checkedboxList instead CheckedListbox.
I would put third property there. but how to check/uncheck checkbox using that property(say bool checked) ??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found solution.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < chklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
      chklistbox.SetItemCheckState(i, (state ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked));
```

`state` is `boolen` value.

Comment: where you have define `state` just define as `bool` and give default value as `true` is it?

Answer (score 16):

If you have a large Items list, this approach may be a little more efficient for *unchecking* items. It requires you only cycle through the items that are actually checked:

```
    private void UncheckAllItems()
    {
        while (chklistbox.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
            chklistbox.SetItemChecked(chklistbox.CheckedIndices[0], false);
    }
```

And if you use multiple CheckedListBox controls throughout your project and wanted to take it a step further, it could be added as an extension method:

```
    public static class AppExtensions
    {
        public static void UncheckAllItems(this System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox clb)
        {
            while (clb.CheckedIndices.Count > 0)
                clb.SetItemChecked(clb.CheckedIndices[0], false);
        }
    }
```

Extension method call:

```
    chklistbox.UncheckAllItems();
```

Answer (score 6):

**Check/Uncheck all list items written below code:**

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chkboxlst.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            chkboxlst.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chkboxlst.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            chkboxlst.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

**To Uncheck/Check all listItems Do the below Code:**

```
 boolean state =false;//False->Uncheck,true->Check

 for (int i = 0; i < chklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
      chklistbox.SetItemCheckState(i, (state ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked));
```